# Using wget in Anaconda Jupyter to get a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

After writing the code in Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda I only get the empty csv file in my local machine environment while the code works fine in a server based environment
`!wget -nv -O china_gdp.csv https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/china_gdp.csv`

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
import wget

url = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses- 
data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/china_gdp.csv'
csv = wget.download(url)
```

This code downloads the csv file.